# Laravel - How to override the request class so that a script is executed whenever an http request is made to the backend?

Tags: php, laravel, overriding, laravel-request

I have managed this by extending the Form request like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use App\Http\Controllers\Root\RootController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Root\ConfigRootController;

class Request extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Intercept the request and make changes
     * 
     */
    protected function getValidatorInstance()
    {
        
        $data = $this->all();

        RootController::setConn($data['url']);
        $Config = ConfigRootController::get_tl_config($data['url']);

        if(isset($data['cookie'])){
            $User = ConfigRootController::getCurrentUser($data['url'],$data['cookie']);
            $GLOBALS['user']=$User;
        }
        $GLOBALS['CONFIG'] = json_decode($Config->getBody()->getContents());

        return parent::getValidatorInstance();
    }
}
```

However this solution has a limitation as it does not allow me to use the `$request->validate()` method in the controller, which is a requirement.

Given that I am using laravel as a stateless API. I need to intercept all requests made and inject the script below right before the controller so that I can access and handle the config data as needed.

```
$data = $this->all();

RootController::setConn($data['url']);
$Config = ConfigRootController::get_tl_config($data['url']);

if(isset($data['cookie'])){
    $User = ConfigRootController::getCurrentUser($data['url'],$data['cookie']);
    $GLOBALS['user']=$User;
}
$GLOBALS['CONFIG'] = json_decode($Config->getBody()->getContents());
```

Here is an attempt via extending the Request class and applying the script in a constructor like so :

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

// use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http;
use App\Http\Controllers\Root\RootController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Root\ConfigRootController;

class Request extends Http\Request
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $data = $this->all();

        RootController::setConn($data['url']);
        $Config = ConfigRootController::get_tl_config($data['url']);

        if(isset($data['cookie'])){
            $User = ConfigRootController::getCurrentUser($data['url'],$data['cookie']);
            $GLOBALS['user']= json_decode($User->getBody()->getContents());
        }
        $GLOBALS['TL_CONFIG'] = json_decode($Config->getBody()->getContents());
    }
}
```

This however results in a 500 internal server error from postman.

Comment: This is a middleware task

Comment: *"I need to intercept all requests made and inject the script below right before the controller [...]"* - That sounds like what a Middleware is supposed to do: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware. Middleware can run before and/or after every request, or for requests that match your needs (via route groups, etc), and can be used to modify things like the `$request` instance, etc.

Comment: sounds like a good candidate for a middleware

Answer (score 0):

As it has been pointed out, the proper way to do this is via middleware :

**First :**

```
php artisan make:middleware BeforeRequest
```

**Then in app\Http\Middleware\BeforeRequest.php :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Root\RootController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Root\ConfigRootController;

class BeforeRequest
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {

        $request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json'); //force the response to be json format

        $data = $request->all();

        RootController::setConn($data['url']);
        $Config = ConfigRootController::get_tl_config($data['url']);

        if(isset($data['cookie'])){
            $User = ConfigRootController::getCurrentUser($data['url'],$data['cookie']);
            $GLOBALS['user']= json_decode($User->getBody()->getContents());
        }
        $GLOBALS['TL_CONFIG'] = json_decode($Config->getBody()->getContents());

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Then in app\Http\Kernel.php :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\BeforeRequest::class, //! add your middleware
    ];
```

And that is all.